# What are threads?

Tags: multithreading

1. What are threads?
2. Why do you think I should care about them?
3. Where would you suggest I go to learn more (I'm working in Delphi, if that matters).

Comment: There are plenty of resources on the web, search a little bit. BTW, Learn about thread pools also... they are very handy :)

Comment: I'm curious. Why was this downvoted. Is there an obvious duplicate of it? Despite the "newbie" nature of the question, I think it's an important one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. [Wikipedia: Thread (computing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computer_science))
2. [Wikipedia: Thread (computing) - Multithreading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29#Multithreading)
3. [Threading in Delphi](http://delphi.about.com/od/kbthread/Threading_in_Delphi.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Threads allow you to utilize multiple processors or cores in a CPU, so they offer tremendous speedups when used properly on specific machines.

Comment: Correct...but fails to differentiate between using multiple threads and multiple processes.

Comment: Threads let you do that, but they were invented long before multi-processor systems were a thing. Their original purpose is to simplify\* programs in which different, stateful activities happen _concurrently_. With threads, the state of each activity is represented by its program counter and, by the contents of its stack. Each thread can be read as if (to some extent) it was an independent, procedural program. Without threads, the state of each activity must be maintained in explicit state objects. Exploiting multiple CPUs is just one reason to have multiple concurrent activities.

Comment: \* Multi-threaded code may be easier to read and understand than some alternatives, but it can be a challenge to _write_ it without introducing serious bugs.

Answer (score 2):

A little history from an "old timer": when I first heard about threads, they were referred to as "threads of control".

One of the earlier popular portable threading libraries was (and still is) "pthreads" or "POSIX Threads". It was derived from the "Concert Multithread Architecture" from Digital Equipment Corporation. It's notable that the [documentation](http://www.devdaily.com/unix/man/man3/pthread_create.3thr.shtml) for pthreads still uses the term "thread of control". From an online man page for the `pthread_create` function:

> pthread_create creates a new thread of control that executes concurrently with the calling thread.

You should care about threads because everything you do on a computer is done in a thread. Even the simplest "Hello, world" program contains at least a single thread.

Things get more interesting with multiple threads. In fact, things get *too* interesting if you're not very careful!

Answer (score 0):

1. The number of 'things' your program/application can do at the same time without being influenced by the other 'things' it is doing at that specific time.
2. Example supporting 1. Lets say your program is a car, but you are not using threads, while opening the door, the door is stuck and you can't close it. Now you can't start your car because there is only one action available and you can't start any other before the previous is ended. If you would be using threads in your program ( the car ) you would be driving around with an open door ;-)
3. What a thread is is fairly easy, using it is language dependent so search for the right documentation and just have some fun :)